# Issue with Template literals after updating angular application from v13 to v15

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I updated my angular application from v13 to v14 and then to v15 as directed by https://update.angular.io/.

But after the update I am having issues with template string in application. JS is throwing following error on every instance where I used template string (`).
[image]

this is one of the location where this issue is occurring
[image]

This is my project's tsconfig

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "./",
      "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "declaration": false,
      "module": "es2015",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "importHelpers": true,
      "target": "ES2022",
      "types": [
        "node",
        "office-js",
        "jest",
        "google-apps-script",
        "uuid",
        "citeproc-types",
        "chrome",
        "jasmine"
      ],
      "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types",
        "node_modules/@external"
      ],
      "lib": [
        "es2018",
        "esnext",
        "dom"
      ],
      "paths": {
        "core-js/es7/reflect": [
          "node_modules/core-js/proposals/reflect-metadata"
        ],
        "core-js/es6/*": [
          "node_modules/core-js/es/*"
        ],
        "lodash/*": [
          "node_modules/@types/lodash-es/*"
        ]
      },
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "useDefineForClassFields": false
    }
}
```

dependencies from my package.json

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "15.12.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "15.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "15.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "15.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "15.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "15.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "15.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "15.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "15.2.10",
    "@microsoft/office-js": "1.1.74",
    "@ngrx/store": "15.4.0",
    "citeproc": "2.4.62",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "3.22.8",
    "custom-event-polyfill": "1.0.7",
    "lodash-es": "4.17.21",
    "ngx-virtual-scroller": "^4.0.3",
    "office-ui-fabric-core": "11.0.1",
    "office-ui-fabric-js": "1.5.0",
    "rxjs": "7.5.6",
    "uuid": "8.3.2",
    "zone.js": "0.11.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "15.2.10",
    "@angular/cli": "15.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "15.2.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "15.2.10",
    "@google/clasp": "2.4.1",
    "@types/chrome": "0.0.193",
    "@types/google-apps-script": "1.0.47",
    "@types/jasmine": "4.0.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.10",
    "@types/jest": "28.1.6",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.182",
    "@types/lodash-es": "4.17.6",
    "@types/lodash.clonedeep": "4.5.7",
    "@types/office-js": "1.0.260",
    "@types/uuid": "8.3.4",
    "del": "6.1.1",
    "gas-webpack-plugin": "2.2.1",
    "gts": "3.1.0",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "gulp-change": "1.0.2",
    "gulp-rename": "2.0.0",
    "gulp-replace": "1.1.3",
    "gulp-typescript": "6.0.0-alpha.1",
    "jasmine-core": "4.2.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "7.0.0",
    "karma": "6.3.20",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "5.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "2.0.0",
    "prettier": "2.7.1",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "9.3.1",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-lint": "0.12.0",
    "tslib": "2.4.0",
    "tslint": "6.1.3",
    "typescript": "4.8.4",
    "webpack": "5.73.0",
    "webpack-cli": "4.10.0",
    "webpack-es3-plugin": "^1.5.2"
  },
```

webpack.config

```
const path = require('path');
const GasPlugin = require('gas-webpack-plugin');
const ES3Plugin = require('webpack-es3-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: {
        'Code.js': './src/google-apps-script/server.ts',
        'Code.ext.js': './src/google-apps-script/api.ts',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'addon-gdocs/[name]',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    plugins: [new GasPlugin(), new ES3Plugin()],
};
```

I tried to modify my typescript version and tsconfig but it didn't workout